# what does $2>anynumber mean in awk script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk

I was going through a shell script given by my teacher and i came across a line `awk ' $2>0.10 && $2 > 0.10 { print $1,$2 }'` can anyone help me to understand what it means? especially `$2>0.10` Is it to print the second column with values greater than 0.10?

Comment: I edit title, question is more awk than shell.

Comment: Did your teacher **really** give you a script that says `$2>0.10 && $2 > 0.10` or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

this will filter any line where second field `$2` is greater `>` than `0.10`.

```
awk ' $2>0.10 && $2 > 0.10 { print $1,$2 }'
```

As is the two test as redundant. when condition are met, first and second filed are printed.

awk use arithmetic comparison greater `>` lower `<` equal `==` not equal `!=`.

In most shell `>` is used for standard output redirection and `2>` for error output redirection.

Comment: thank you for your help.